# ASP.NET MVC Razor - Navigate without refresh master page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC application (using Razor) i want avoid master page refresh every time that i click on a link.

My master page has this structure:

```
<html>
....
<div id="main">
@RenderBody()
</div>
...
</html>
```

Link buttons can be both in master page and in content page. How must be structured my pages?

Comment: You should take a look into the partial views: http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html

Comment: may be i didn't use them good, but it continue to refresh master page also using PartialView

Answer (score 1):

Every time a view is retrieved using a standard call, master view is refreshed.

If you want to avoid this, you should create all your views using PartialViews, and do AJAX calls. So, when you click a link, an ajax call is performed, the partial view is retrieved and a DOM element (usually a div) is filled with the contents of partial view.

Doing this by hand is possible but you will have to face a lot of issues. If you really want to do a SPA (Single Page Application) start looking AngularJs, Durandal, Backbone or any Javascript library that help you on this! (i. e. take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709766/Tutorial-for-Building-SPA-using-AngularJS).

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i'm not able to understand how to put PartialView in my MasterPage. Do i must replace @RenderBody()?

Comment: No. You can leave your master page as is. You need an initial full view (i. e. /home/index). This view will render a  DOM element (i. e. a <div>) and using AJAX calls you will "fill" this div with the contents of partial views. This is basically an SPA app. For an example of doing it manually (not recommended) can look at my blog (sorry, is in spanish): http://geeks.ms/blogs/etomas/archive/2011/10/08/aplicaciones-quot-de-una-sola-p-225-gina-con-html5-y-asp-net-mvc.aspx. But i rcommend you to use some library like AngularJs!

Comment: I'd like to use AngularJs, i like write js, but now it's too late because the project it's already advanced. Your solution was for sure the cleanest but not simple, thank you for help. I decided for other solution, i ll explain in answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we decided to use an old and deprecated solution, but in my particular case (screen size fixed, no mobile, support just for ff) it works very good. I use iframe html tags: creating a custom starting web page that contains 3 different iframe that call their own function controller.
I don't recommend it, but may be for someone can be useful, in case of emergency like mine..